# How to append css Class name to particular image src url

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have certain images all in blogspot.com, and i want to append class name to it via Javascript which are under particular div.

for an instance :-

```
<div class="outer-post">
    <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <!-- more images -->
    <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/100.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
</div>
```

and i want to convert all to :-

```
<div class="outer-post">
    <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/1.jpg" class="myPic" width="200" height="200" />
    <!-- more images -->
    <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/100.jpg" class="myPic" width="200" height="200" />
</div>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using jQuery `$("div.outer-post img").addClass("myPic")`

Comment: Thanks bro, I will mark this as answer.. it asks me to wait for 10 minutes :)

Comment: its not working.. there are many images inside outer-post. :(

Comment: this is my code `<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("div.outer-post img").addClass("myPic")
    });
    </script>`

Comment: `<div class="outer-post">
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/1.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;">
<img border="0" height="475" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/1.jpg" width="640" /></a></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/1.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;">
<img border="0" height="475" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/1.jpg" width="640" /></a></div>
</div>`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

```
 $(selector).addClass(className);
```

As per your requirement use

```
 $("div.outer-post img").addClass("myPic");
```

Edit: As per your comments use

```
 $("div.outer-post").find("img").addClass("myPic");
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tSZeh/1/)

Comment: there are many images inside outer-post, this code didnot work, here is my code :- `<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(document).ready(function($) { $("div.outer-post img").addClass("myPic") }); </script>`

Comment: I am still facing some problem, but i will do some debugging via your jsFiddle. Thanks a lot bro :)